# Using variable as part of name of new file in python

Tags: python, fasta

I'm fairly new to python and I'm having an issue with my python script (split_fasta.py). Here is an example of my issue:

```
list = ["1.fasta", "2.fasta", "3.fasta"]
for file in list:
    contents = open(file, "r")
    for line in contents:
        if line[0] == ">":
            new_file = open(file + "_chromosome.fasta", "w")
            new_file.write(line)
```

I've left the bottom part of the program out because it's not needed. My issue is that when I run this program in the same direcoty as my fasta123 files, it works great:

> python split_fasta.py *.fasta

But if I'm in a different directory and I want the program to output the new files (eg. 1.fasta_chromsome.fasta) to my current directory...it doesn't:

> python /home/bin/split_fasta.py /home/data/*.fasta

This still creates the new files in the same directory as the fasta files. The issue here I'm sure is with this line:

```
new_file = open(file + "_chromosome.fasta", "w")
```

Because if I change it to this:

```
new_file = open("seq" + "_chromosome.fasta", "w")
```

It creates an output file in my current directory.

I hope this makes sense to some of you and that I can get some suggestions.

Comment: You should checkout BioPython

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are giving the full path of the old file, plus a new name. So basically, if `file == /home/data/something.fasta`, the output file will be `file +  "_chromosome.fasta"` which is `/home/data/something.fasta_chromosome.fasta`

If you use `os.path.basename` on `file`, you will get the name of the file (i.e. in my example, `something.fasta`)

From @Adam Smith

> You can use `os.path.splitext` to get rid of the `.fasta`
>
> ```
> basename, _ = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))
> ```

---

Getting back to the code example, I saw many things not recommended in Python. I'll go in details.

Avoid shadowing builtin names, such as `list`, `str`, `int`... It is not explicit and can lead to potential issues later.

When opening a file for reading or writing, you should use the `with` syntax. This is highly recommended since it takes care to close the file.

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
with open(new_filename, "w") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

If you have an empty line in your file, `line[0] == ...` will result in a `IndexError` exception. Use `line.startswith(...)` instead.

Final code :

```
files = ["1.fasta", "2.fasta", "3.fasta"]
for file in files:
    with open(file, "r") as input:
        for line in input:
            if line.startswith(">"):
                new_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file)) + "_chromosome.fasta"
                with open(new_name, "w") as output:
                    output.write(line)
```

Often, people come at me and say "*that's hugly*". Not really :). The levels of indentation makes clear what is which context.

Comment: and you can use `os.path.splitext` to get rid of the extra `.fasta`! `basename, _ = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))`

Comment: Added. Thanks, I didn't know this one. Worth reading the `os.path` doc again :)

Comment: This is great! Thanks all for your help and definitely feel free to make edits @FunkySayu